# Send parameters to route in symfony twig

Tags: php, symfony, parameters, routes, twig

I have a route defined like this:

```
reuzze_reuzze_categoryentitiespage:
pattern:  /category/entities/{category_id}
defaults: { _controller: ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:Category:entities }
```

I have categories in my view that I want to loop through and create hyperlinks like this:

```
{% for name, category in categories %}
    <li>{{ name }}</li>
    <ul>
        {% for key, string in category %}
            <li><a href="{{ path('reuzze_reuzze_categoryentitiespage', {'category_id': {{ key }} }) }}">{{ string }}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
{% endfor  %}
```

But when I do this I always get this error:

```
A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in ReuzzeReuzzeBundle:Search:entitiesfromsearch.html.twig at line 12
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace,

```
<li><a href="{{ path('reuzze_reuzze_categoryentitiespage', {'category_id': {{ key }} }) }}">{{ string }}</a></li>
```

with,

```
<li><a href="{{ path('reuzze_reuzze_categoryentitiespage', {'category_id': key }) }}">{{ string }}</a></li>
```

Put another way, `{{ ... }}` twig delimiters can't be nested. All the variables included in the the first delimiters are interpreted. No need to wrap the `key` variable by any other nested delimiters.